# Popup scroller in Mudblazor page load

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am working on a Blazor Web Assembly project using MudBlazor. I have called 4 WebAPI methods to load 4 lists respectively in OnInitializedAsync method. It takes times around 10 seconds. I want during these 10 seconds a popup scroller should be displayed on the screen enabling user to wait. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the components `OnAfterRenderAsync` method to load your data instead of using `OnInitializedAsync`. This will allow you to display a loading state while the data is being fetched.

Here's an example.

```
@if (_loadingData)
{
    <MudOverlay Visible="true">
        <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Secondary" Indeterminate="true" />
    </MudOverlay>
}
else
{
    <!-- your element and data -->
    <ul>
    @foreach(var item in _stuffToDisplay){
        <li>@item</li>
    }
    </ul>
}           

@code{
    bool _loadingData = true;
    List<string> _stuffToDisplay;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            // load your data here
            _stuffToDisplay = await GetDataAsync(); 

            _loadingData = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    async Task<List<string>> GetDataAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);

        return new List<string>(){
            "my custom data1",
            "my custom data2",
            "my custom data3",
            "my custom data4",
        };
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QamROMmwkFDewDYH)